# Complete tmux reset

Tags: macos, tmux

I was wondering if it is possible to completely reset tmux (the UI mainly) ?
I have tried deleting my `~/.tmux.conf` and reinstalling tmux it but I always ended up with the same status bar I had defined.

Comment: What configuration did you define in `~/.tmux.conf` (and how did you defined it) that you are now expecting to see changed/reverted to default?

Comment: changed the keybindings, the status bar and the borders but when I deleted the `~/.tmux.conf` and restarted tmux they hadn't changed

Comment: how did you "restart" tmux? you can try `tmux kill-server` then create a new session to check if your customization are gone.

Comment: @Kent that was it, didn't kill my sessions

Comment: @h.demoff what did you mean "didn't kill my sess.."?

Comment: @Kent well apparently I had 10 old sessions open and each time I started tmux with `tmux` it attached me to the oldest. I left the sessions by `C-d` bash.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Had forgotten to kill the existing sessions:

```
tmux kill-server
```

was the solution *(credits to: @Kent)*