# tmux ctrl+d does not detach from session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tmux, npm-start

I am running a server with Ubuntu 14.04 using nodejs with 
    `npm start` 
command. 

I start tmux session with 
    `tmux`
command, then do 
    `npm start`
and finally do 
    `ctrl+d`
to detach. 
But `ctrl+d` would not work for me. Whatever I am using, it only detaches me from the session if I stop all the processes. 
It is also same problem when I am trying to detach from session with  `mongod` running.
Any ideas?

PS: running ctrl+a+d does not work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When issuing a tmux command, [you need to first use the prefix key combination](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Key_bindings). By default, this is `C-b` (ctrl+b).

If the default prefix isn't working, it's possible that you changed it or, if you're using someone else's .tmux.conf, they may have changed it. You can run `tmux list-keys | grep send-prefix` from your shell to determine what the current prefix is.

So, in order to detach from a running session, you'd type `C-b d`.

Comment: Thank you! It really helped!

Comment: For anyone else finding this question having trouble detaching, even when using the correct command, try running `tmux kill-server`. I ran into an issue where a tmux session was running on a remote server, and every time I ssh'd in I would already be in a running session, and `C-b d` would not detach, very weird but that command fixed it. 
Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295615/complete-tmux-reset